# Copying files in JavaScript depending on a date (timing)

Tags: javascript, file, date, copy, timing

I am having some problems trying to copy a file from my database to another URL of it.
This file is a huge one, so I would like to know how to copy a part of it. For example:

Copying this file between 30/11/2016 10:15 and 30/11/2016 10:27.

Inside of this file I have some coordinates and each of them have a "date" field. I mean, part of the text of the file has written a date, so I would like to know if it is possible copy just a part of the text depending of that "string date"

I explain it better with an example:

Text File:
   Coordinate 1:
     "date" X

Coordinate 2:
     "date" Y

Does anybody know a Script in Javascript for solving this?

Comment: If it is only one file there is no way of determining the changes between dates unless you do something like versioning. All you have is last modified date

Comment: Inside of this file I have some coordinates and each of them have a "date" field. I mean, part of the text of the file has written a date, so I would like to  know if it is possible copy just a part of the text depending of that "string date"

Answer (score 1):

You can use FileReader to read the file:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    // e.target.result should contain the text
};

reader.readAsText(file);
```

Now inside that function you can search for your dates even by regex or whatever you like and find the lines which you want to crop.

**However**

Remember that if the file is large reading it in client side is not a good idea.